# Get UIScrollView target movement with paging enabled?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I have a Sprite Kit scene with `pagingEnabled` UIScrollView implemented for transition between home screens in my app. Each home screen has a button in the middle of it that takes you into that part of the app. When user scrolls between screens, the button texture of that screen should be animated to the texture of the new page's button (using array of texture frames). I've implemented the drag part of this, so when user starts dragging between screens, the button texture changes to the new in-between frame according to the offset while dragging. Now to the next part: when touch lefts the screen, an action should be run to animate it to the new button texture using the rest frames. The problem is that I need to know the target before the scrolling is made so I can extract the right texture frames and change the screen button according to it while scroll is being made. It wouldn't be smooth to freeze the button texture until the scrolling is made and then run the animation.

So, is there a way I can detect the next target of my UIScrollView when drag ends? Mainly, I need to know if it's about to scroll to (1) the right page, (2) the left page or (3) return back to its initial position.

I've read about `scrollViewWillEndDragging:withVelocity:targetContentOffset` delegate method. Unfortunately, it isn't called with `pagingEnabled` property set to YES.

Comment: `scrollViewWillEndDragging:...` will indeed get called with pagingEnabled set to YES.

Comment: Believe it or not, I didn't even bothered trying it! I've just tried it now and it really gets called! Then why the hell Apple did mention that it won't in the documentation here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiscrollviewdelegate_protocol/reference/uiscrollviewdelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIScrollViewDelegate/scrollViewWillEndDragging:withVelocity:targetContentOffset: Isn't that strange? Should I really still use it with confidence? I'm confused!

Comment: My bad, obviously Apple is more correct than SO (and me).  I was actually referring to `scrollViewDidEndDragging:willDecelerate:`

Comment: Can I trust the fact that it's being called in my simulator? It provides me with everything I need! :\

Comment: Given that the docs say it won't be, I wouldn't.  I'd use didEndDragging since it's supposed to be sent.

Comment: The idea is that I need to get the target offset of the scroll to be made, which is provided ONLY by the first method.